# XMLBeans get_store() method returns null

Tags: java, apache, apache-axis, xmlbeans

I am developing a Axis2 based WebServices with XMLBeans binding. I have generated the code by using WSDL2Java generator and tried testing it with sample values set in the request.

In one of the setter methods (auto-generated code) I found the below code. The method `get_store()` returns a null value and hence I get a NullPointerException.

```
target = (org.apache.xmlbeans.SimpleValue)
    get_store().find_element_user(TRANSACTIONTYPE$0, 0);
```

I tried Google to find the solution and found [similar issue](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/xmlbeans-user/200809.mbox/%3C20080924115206468.00000006684@CEZAR01%3E) with no solution specified.

Is there any work around for this issue?? Kindly help me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This issue got resolved!!

I was actually trying to instantiate a response object in a normal Java way and hence i got the above mentioned exception while running my WebServices.

**Wrong way** - `ResponseType responseType = new ResponseType();`

**Correct way** - `ResponseType responseType = ResponseType.Factory.newInstance();`

Comment: I'm having same problem in a getter method... But I'm not sure how you solved this... Can you post some lines of your client where do you use the generated classes? It would be a great help!